Are seaplanes with floats more aerodynamically efficient (less drag) than planes with tires?
After getting an unexpected answer from What's the fastest fixed gear airplane? post, I wonder if seaplanes with floats are more aerodynamically efficient (less drag) than fixed tire airplanes?

I have much seaplane flying and can tell you that, in general, floats will take about 15-30% off a landplane's cruise speed. For example, a DeHavilland Beaver will cruise at low altitude on wheels, about 115kt. On floats, it'll do about 95 kt.
A Cessna 180 on wheels cruises around 130kt at low altitude, and on floats about 115ish.
The floats cost speed, some payload, that is, payload is reduced by part of the weight of the floats (some credit is taken for the lift they produce, so if they weigh, say, 500lbs, the deduction from the useful load may only be 200 lbs).
And they move the vertical axis neutral point forward, reducing yaw stability (weathervaning tendency) and usually require added fin area at the tail (later Cessna 180s, and 185s, have an oversize dorsal fin in the basic aircraft, and don't require any additional fin area when on floats).

A decisive answer!

@Fattie Yeah, I was about to say, that's a damn good answer. Can't be more complete. Also, i've always been curious about that. I figured if I flew over water, I'd only use floats!

Fixed landing gear is draggy -- the wheels, tires, and brakes are very draggy -- some of that can be improved with wheel pants and other fairings.
Floats can be shaped somewhat aerodynamically, but they still have large frontal and wetted area.  They usually have a step with no aerodynamic fairing.
The structure to hold the wheels or floats can be thought of similarly -- struts and wires can be streamlined, but they are still draggy.  Having two or three times as much of this stuff (like a floatplane will) will certainly cause more drag.
I think the question you're really after is a comparison of a like-to-like aircraft...
Would a Schneider Trophy aircraft have been faster if it was not required to be a seaplane and instead was fitted with fixed landing gear.
I am confident saying yes, a Schneider Trophy aircraft modified to have reasonably cleaned up fixed gear would have less drag than the floatplane version.
That said, the benefits of retractible landing gear were well understood at the time.  A comparable land plane racer at the time would certainly have had retractible landing gear.
If they had had a technology for retractible floats, the Schneider Trophy aircraft would have used them.
Edit:
Floats and the structure that support them are also heavy.  More weight means more induced drag.
A simple fixed gear would certainly be lighter than floats.  A retractible gear would be heaver than fixed -- but still lighter than floats.
At Schneider Trophy speeds, accepting the weight penalty (compared to fixed gear) of retractable gear would certainly be worth the drag benefit.  But either solution would be lighter and cleaner than floats.

One of the innovations in Schneider Trophy competitors was eliminating stuts and wires.  Even a fairly fat, but well streamlined single float leg was a lot cleaner than a narrow leg with support wires.  Likewise, cantilever wings and tail surfaces came along pretty early; innovations from this race series fed into military pursuit aircraft a decade before the conflicts in Europe brewed up into World War.

Another element of Schneider Trophy aircraft was they were optimised for high cruise speed & also had relatively high stall & V2 speeds. They had quite extreme fixed-pitch propellers meaning they weren't remotely efficient at low speeds leading to very long take-off distances. At the time there were few paved runways & wheeled undercarriage for these aircraft would have had to have been built somewhat more ruggedly than other land aircraft due to time & speed on the grass or gravel.

At least the large float area could be used for cooling, reducing the need for (also very draggy) radiators. Still, floats clearly produce more drag than wheels. +1

Also note that many float planes and flying boats had (semi)retractable outrigger floats for a reason: drag reduction.

One point not addressed is that float planes used the floats as fuel tanks, which enabled the fuselage to be smaller and the wings to be slimmer, and improved stability. Yes, it is totally counter-intuitive to weigh down the floats with fuel, but the floats have to support the same all-up weight when on the water, wherever you put the fuel.

If the majority of the floatation is provided by the hull (ie, a flyingboat rather than a seaplane) then certainly adding wheels would make it worse. But such hulls are a compromise between aerodynamics and hydrodynamics, meaning it's not especially good at either.
On the other hand, if you start with a regular plane and add floats (replacing normal undercarriage), that will clearly make it a lot worse, since they have enormous frontal cross section and they move the aerodynamic drags centre down, requiring other charges to compensate. But at least in this case you can add wheels that barely protrude from the bottom of the floats, with minimal impact.
You might also like to consider skids for landing on packed snow or ice. These are usually fitted in addition to wheels, and can often be retracted along with the wheels, so there is minimal difference to the drag once airborne.

Would it be practical to have a plane whose hull was not designed to float when stationary, but could use retractable waster-ski-like outriggers for takeoff and landing?

Skis aren't buoyant, so they will sink as soon as your speed drops below minimum aquaplaning speed; I'm hoping the hull is buoyant! That would only be useful for landings, and you would probably want to park on land.
If you mean some kind of retractable floats, they would require much larger bays to retract into, impairing the internal capacity of the aircraft. Or you could have some kind of hybrid that partially retracts, with their remaining exposed surfaces shaped to match the aerodynamic profile of the aircraft.

A flyingboat would probably be simpler - no moving parts - and not much worse aerodynamically; modelling would be needed to check this.

My limited understanding of hydrodynamics and aerodynamics would suggest that to minimize drag in the water during takeoff one would want a hull shape that would push fluid to the sides, which would reduce the amount of lift the hull would provide once airborne.  Additionally, a seaplane hull needs to be wide enough at the bottom to minimize draft.  If a seaplane could sit lower in the water when not taking off or landing, it could use a hull shape much closer to that of a normal airliner.

@supercat Prior to transitioning to hydroplaning, you start with a basic boat design ("U" shaped cross-section with a sharp bow), but modified to balance buoyancy and hull drag both as functions of vertical displacement, and lift as a function of speed, so that you can smoothly lift out of the water on the way to hydroplaning. Once you've transitioned to hydroplaning you want a fairly flat bottom that can skip over the surface; simple skis would work for that.

Simple skis would work, but I would think they would have the same drawback in the air as fixed wheels.  I would think that retractable skis could offer the same advantage as retractable wheels.
